# Make WebView behave according to device (phone/tablet)

Tags: android, webview, responsive-design, tablet, smartphone

I have a responsive webpage and I managed to make it scale on mobile devices using viewport metatag. Now I need a WebView to render the webpage in mobile version on smartphones and in desktop version on tablets.
Android seems not to do this by default since tablets too render the page using the responsive version.

Basically I need to know if the WebView is loaded in a tablet layout or in a phone layout and then make it use the responsive design or not.

For example: I want that the same webView render the Facebook homepage (or any other common site that has a responsive layout) in mobile version on smartphones but in desktop version on tablets.

How can I do that?

Comment: Load one page or another is more related to the webpage than the webview

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "how do I do this?", please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you really need a question mark? I've edited the question, please check it out.

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: @webo80 The page to be loaded is the same, what changes is the device.

Comment: @CommonsWare I haven't tried anything, I just can't find a way to tell the webview which version to use according to device size

Comment: Since "tablet" is a marketing term, not a technical one, what *exactly* is the technical dividing line between "smartphones" and "tablets" for your use case? Is the URL fixed (i.e., you have two hardcoded values and are choosing between them) or dynamic (i.e., you are getting values from a Web service, or a dynamic Web page, and are choosing between them)? Are you trying to make your size decision in Java, JavaScript, or CSS (e.g., media queries)? Most responsive designs are implemented in one page that dynamically adapts. Apparently, yours does not, so we need more to go on to help you.

Comment: Yes it adatps dynamically, I used the viewport meta tag and it works fine on small devices and on desktop. On large mobile devices (in Android they use large layouts) the page gets rendered as on small devices even if I zoom out, while I want it to be rendered in desktop version.